# Java - Program works only for localhost

Tags: java

I use the following code for the client

```
InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"); 
Socket socket = new Socket(host,serverPort);
```

and for the server

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portAdd);
Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
```

It works if I am using localhost but not when I use an IP address.
Firewall is not blocking the connection.

Comment: then its probably an infrastructure issue. we need more information than that

Comment: by infrastructure you mean something related to my ISP/router/Nat?

Comment: What ip address - the address of a remote machine, or the IP address of your own machine? Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 if you are trying to connect to your own machine?

Comment: @DaveH I am only trying in my own machine, for 127.0.0.1 is working with no problem. I only have a problem when I am trying to connect to my own machine using my public IP address.

Comment: Have you verified that you can really talk to that IP address? For example by opening a stupid telnet connection to it?

Comment: Server name seems to be mapped to local ip only. Can you check hosts file for name and ip mapping?

Comment: @Jägermeister you are right i didn't check that, I cannot

Comment: Then, your question is more about infrastructure; in that case, superuser.com would be a better place for it.